# Numpy/Python zero division error

Tags: python, numpy

I don't know what is the problem here and I didn't realize how to find a way to resolve it. Actually, it gives the error `ZeroDivisionError: division by zero`. However there is nothing to be zero to divide to it, as far as I divided to 180 and it's not zero.

```
C1 = np.array([AA, north1, north1, north1, north1, D1, north1, north1, north1, north1]);
z = np.zeros((len(C1), 1));
C1 = np.concatenate([np.array(C1)[:,None], np.array(z)],axis=1);
B1 = C1 * [np.arange(np.cos(-90*np.pi/180), 0,np.sin(-90*np.pi/180)),np.arange(0, 1,0), np.arange(-np.sin(-90*np.pi/180),0,np.cos(-90*np.pi/180))];
```

P.S. Here I tried to do cosd:

```
np.cos(-90*np.pi/180)
```

Comment: `np.arange(0, 1,0)` does not work. Just change it to e.g. `np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is coming from `np.arange(0, 1,0)` which is trying to generate an array of values from 0 to 1 separated by 0. The function signature is `numpy.arange([start, ]stop, [step, ]dtype=None)` so you should have a nonzero step.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to multiple my matrix with this new matrix with cos and sin . in matlab it looks like B1=C1*[ cosd(-90)  0  sind(-90); 0 1 0; -sind(-90) 0 cosd(-90)];

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of below statement

```
np.arange(0, 1, 0)
```

The documentation of `numpy.arange()` does not say anything about having non-zero step.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html